# Is it possible to make something like longjump in Perl inside EV callbacks?

Tags: perl, anyevent, dbd-pg

I am trying to emulate synchronous control flow in an asynchronous environment.

The purpose is to support DB requests without callbacks or blocking on request.

I am trying to use the [`Coro`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Coro) module, but I think I don't understand it in full.

Here are the code snippets:

```
sub execute {
    my ($sth, @vars) = @_;

    my $res   = $sth->SUPER::execute(@vars);
    my $dbh   = $sth->{Database};
    my $async = new Coro::State;
    my $new;
    $new = new Coro::State sub {
        my $w;
        while (!$dbh->pg_ready) {
            $w = AnyEvent->io(
                fh   => $dbh->{pg_socket},
                poll => 'r',
                cb   => sub {
                    if($dbh->pg_ready) {
                        $w = undef;
                        $new->transfer($async);
                    } 
                }
            ) if not $w;
            print "run once before statement: $sth->{Statement}\n";
            EV::run EV::RUN_ONCE;
        }
    };
    $async->transfer($new);
    $res = $dbh->pg_result;
    $res;
}
```

Here is the testing code:

```
my $cv = AE::cv;

ok(my $dbh = db_connect(), 'connected');
ok(my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select pg_sleep(2)'), 'prepared');

my $start_time = time;
ok($sth->execute(), 'executed');

my $duration = time - $start_time;
ok(($duration > 1 && $duration < 3), 'slept');
is(ref($dbh), 'DBIx::PgCoroAnyEvent::db', 'dbh class');
is(ref($sth), 'DBIx::PgCoroAnyEvent::st', 'sth class');

my $status   = 0;
my $finished = 0;

for my $t (1 .. 10) {
    $finished += 1 << $t;
}

for my $t (1 .. 10) {

    my $timer;

    $timer = AE::timer 0.01 + $t/100, 0, sub {

        ok(my $dbh = db_connect(), "connected $t");
        ok(my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select pg_sleep(' . $t . ')'), "prepared $t");
        my $start_time = time;
        ok($sth->execute(), "executed $t");

        my $duration = time - $start_time;
        ok(($duration > $t - 1 && $duration < $t + 1), "slept $t");

        print "duration: $t: $duration\n";

        $status += 1 << $t;
        if ($status == $finished) {
            $cv->send;
        }

        undef $timer;
    };
}

$cv->recv;
```

Full module and test scripts are here [`DBIx::PgCoroAnyEvent`](https://github.com/jef-sure/dbd-pg-cae/blob/master/lib/DBIx/PgCoroAnyEvent.pm) and here [`01_sleeps.t`](https://github.com/jef-sure/dbd-pg-cae/blob/master/t/01_sleeps.t)

Can someone have a look and explain me what is wrong there?

Comment: [Return::MultiLevel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Return::MultiLevel) is sort of like longjmp but I know nothing about Coro or how they would interact.

Comment: Return::MultiLevel doesn't pass my needs. Sorry.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but you should avoid `undef $timer` as it forces a garbage-collection cycle, and Perl is usually much better at knowing when it should free memory than you are. If you want to de-initialise a variable then write `$timer = undef`. Also, in this case, `$timer` goes out of scope and gets destroyed at the end of each iteration of the `for` loop anyway, so there's no point in changing its value.

Comment: @Borodin Perl has no garbage collection cycles.

Comment: @melpomene: It releases the memory for re-use. What would you prefer to call it?

Comment: @Borodin Well, it calls `free()`. I don't think that's comparable to garbage collection.

Comment: @melpomene: It's doesn't call `free`, it retains the memory for its own use but deallocates it from the variable, and it's generally better not to force that to happen, otherwise you'll get into a deallocate/reallocate cycle which is wasteful

Comment: I believe there's no difference between `undef $var` and `$var = undef`.

Comment: @Anton Petrusevich, `undef $var;` is different than `$var = undef;`. The latter doesn't free any memory, making future use of the variable more efficient. It doesn't matter here (even though the same var is used for each loop pass, because it never contains anything other than undef or a reference), but using `undef $var;` is a bad habit.

Comment: @Anton Petrusevich, What output are you getting? What problem are you having?

Comment: @Anton Petrusevich, `perl -MDevel::Size=total_size -E'$x = "x"x20; say total_size($x); $x=undef; say total_size($x); undef $x; say total_size($x);'` prints 54, 54, 32 (exact numbers may vary). Notice that doing `$var=undef` did not change the size, while `undef $var;` did?

Comment: @ikegami Try [this](http://pastebin.com/BCAPcuPy). It clearly shows than I am right

Comment: @Anton Petrusevich, Stop trying to prove there's no difference after I showed there is one. The fact that *you* can't find one doesn't indicate there isn't one.

Comment: @ikegami have you tried?

Comment: @Anton Petrusevich, Yes, but it only demonstrates that *you* couldn't find a difference even though there is one. Did you try mine?

Comment: You are allocating scalar, it can be different due to some optimizations.

Comment: It is. `undef $var;` specifically disables optimizations. That's why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @ikegami have _you_ found difference in my prorgam?

Comment: There is no difference in your program. I already said that yesterday. ("*It doesn't matter here, but using `undef $var;` is a bad habit.*")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115652/discussion-between-anton-petrusevich-and-ikegami).

Comment: I changed code in execute(), nothing changed. I get failing tests and then coredump. perl 5.20.3 and coro 6.51.

Comment: @ikegami here is the [output](https://gist.github.com/jef-sure/a55696b3f495ee5d590456d3145c6459)

Comment: Don't spread your question over 4 pages, and leave out anything that's not necessary. Version of Coro and Perl are also obviously relevant here, so they should be provided. Coro 6.5 seems to be in flux (since another version was released since we last talked), so your testing needs to be performed with Perl 5.20 (or earlier) and Coro 6.49.

Answer (score 0):

eval+die is the typical method in Perl.

```
eval { some_function( @args ); };
if( $@ ){
    # caught longjmp
}
...
sub some_function {
    ...
    if( some_condition ){
        die "throw longjmp"
    }
    ...
}
```